# Neural Network Genetic Algorithm unexplained error

Tags: c++, runtime-error, genetic-algorithm

I have been investigating Neural Networks for some time and have trained an XOR network using genetic algorithms. At the moment I am working on a project that will predict the state of water given temperature and pressure. I have tested every function individually and the feedforward/error calculation of the neural network seems to work fine. The genetic algorithm appeared to be working fine (the error of each species was going down) until suddenly the program stopped working. After various trial and error experiments I appear to have located the problem to my chooseParent function.

```
do{
    NeuralNet *Children = new NeuralNet[POP];
    for(int i =0 ; i < POP ;  i++)
    {
        A = chooseParent(Population);
        B = chooseParent(Population);
        crossOver(Population[A], Population[B], Children[i]);
        transferGenes(Children[i], Population[i]);
        Population[i].calculateError();
    }
    delete[] Children;
    Children = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < POP ;  i++)
    {
        cout << Population[i].getError() << endl;
    }cout << endl;
}while(Population[0].getError() > 60);
    return 0;
```

I concluded this because when I replaced the chooseParent function to the following:

```
 for(int i =0 ; i < POP ;  i++)
    {
        A = rand()%20;
        B = rand()%20;
        crossOver(Population[A], Population[B], Children[i]);
        transferGenes(Children[i], Population[i]);
        Population[i].calculateError();
    }
```

The program no longer stops working. Here is the chooseParent function. I have tested it individually and it appears to work perfectly.

```
int chooseParent(NeuralNet population[POP]) ///using probability to select parents
{
    int greatestError = population[0].getError();
    for(int i =1 ; i < POP ;  i++)
    {
        if(population[i].getError() > greatestError)
            greatestError = population[i].getError();
    }
    int totalFitness = 0;

    for(int i =0 ; i < POP; i++)
    {
      population[i].setScore(greatestError +1 - population[i].getError());
      totalFitness = totalFitness + population[i].getScore();
    }

    int random = rand()%totalFitness +1;
    int parentSelector = 0;
    int parentIndex;
    for(int i=0; parentSelector<random;i++)
    {
        parentSelector = parentSelector + population[i].getScore();
        parentIndex = i;
    }

    return parentIndex;
}
```

I will post the full code below although I think the problem lies somewhere above.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
const int Ntrain =59;
const int inputs =3;
const int hidden = 5;
const int outputs =3;
const int POP = 50;


using namespace std;

float randFloat(); ///declaring functions
float Sigmoid(float A);

class NeuralNet
{
public:
    NeuralNet()
    {
        ///assigning values to each weight
        for(int i = 0; i < hidden-1 ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < inputs ;  j++)
            {
                weights1[i][j] = randFloat();
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < outputs ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < hidden ;  j++)
            {
                weights2[i][j] = randFloat();
            }
        }
    }

///prints weights
    void printWeights()
    {
     cout << "weights1:" << endl;
     for(int i = 0; i < hidden-1 ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < inputs ;  j++)
            {
                cout << weights1[i][j] << "  ";
            }cout << endl;
        }
    cout << endl << "weights2:" << endl;
     for(int i = 0; i < outputs ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < hidden ;  j++)
            {
                cout << weights2[i][j] << "  ";
            }cout << endl;
        }
    }
    void printTraining()
    {
        for(int i = 0 ;  i < Ntrain ;  i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 6 ; j ++)
            {
                cout << training[i][j] << " ";
            }cout << endl;
        }
    }

    float feedForward(int trainingIndex)
    {
        float hiddenNeuronSum[hidden-1]; ///sum of imputs to each node in hidden layer
        for(int i = 0 ;  i  < hidden-1 ;  i ++)///for each hidden neurone
        {
            hiddenNeuronSum[i] = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < inputs ; j ++ ) ///for each weight
            hiddenNeuronSum[i] = hiddenNeuronSum[i] + (weights1[i][j])*(training[trainingIndex][j]);
        }

        for(int i = 0 ;  i < hidden-1 ; i++) ///sigmoid it
        {
            hiddenNeuronSum[i] = Sigmoid(hiddenNeuronSum[i]);
        }
        ///pass onto next layer
        float outputNeuronSum[outputs];
        for(int i = 0; i < outputs ;  i ++)///for each output
        {
            outputNeuronSum[i] = 0;
            for(int j  = 0;  j  < hidden-1 ; j ++)///for each neurone in hidden layer
            {
                outputNeuronSum[i] = outputNeuronSum[i] + (weights2[i][j])*(hiddenNeuronSum[j]);
            }
            outputNeuronSum[i] = outputNeuronSum[i] + weights2[i][hidden-1];
        }


        for(int i = 0;  i < outputs ; i ++)
        {
            outputNeuronSum[i] = Sigmoid(outputNeuronSum[i]);
        }///sigmoid it again

        float error =  0;
        for(int i = 0;  i < outputs ;  i ++)
        {
            error = error + abs(training[trainingIndex][i+3] - outputNeuronSum[i]); ///calculate the error from each output node
        }
        return error;
    }
    float getError() ///returns error
    {
        return totalerror;
    }
    void calculateError() ///calculates each error from each output using training set
    {
        totalerror = 0;
        for(int i = 0  ;  i < Ntrain ;  i ++)
        {
            totalerror = totalerror + feedForward(i);
        }
    }
    void setScore(int score) ///sets fitness score
    {
        fitnessScore = score;
    }

    friend void crossOver(NeuralNet a, NeuralNet b, NeuralNet &c);
    friend void transferGenes(NeuralNet a, NeuralNet &b);
    friend void fittestSpecies(NeuralNet n);
    int getScore()
    {
        return fitnessScore;
    }
private:
    float weights1[hidden-1][inputs]; ///weights in layer one
    float weights2[outputs][hidden]; ///weights in layers two
    float totalerror;
    int fitnessScore;
    float training[Ntrain][6] = {
    ///{Bias, log(Pa), Kelvin *10^-2, S, L ,G} the error is calculated using the last 3 values
    {1, 5.0, 2.5, 1.0, 0, 0} ,
    {1, 7.0, 3.15, 0, 1.0, 0} ,
    {1, 3.0, 4.76, 0, 0, 1.0},
    //3

    ///solids
    {1, 7.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0, 0},
    {1, 7.0, 2.5, 1.0, 0, 0},
    {1, 6.0, 1.5, 1.0, 0, 0},
    {1, 6.0, 2.5, 1.0, 0, 0},
    {1, 5.0, 1.5, 1.0, 0, 0},
    {1, 5.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0, 0},
    {1, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0, 0},
    {1, 4.0, 2.5, 1.0, 0, 0},
    {1, 3.0, 1.5, 1.0, 0, 0},
    {1, 3.0, 2.5, 1.0, 0, 0},
    {1, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0, 0},
    {1, 2.0, 2.5, 1.0, 0, 0},
    {1, 1.0, 1.5, 1.0, 0, 0},
    {1, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0, 0},
    {1, 1.0, 2.5, 1.0, 0, 0},

//15
    ///liquids

    {1, 1.0, 2.5, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 1.0, 3.0, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 1.0, 3.5, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 1.0, 4.5, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 1.0, 5.0, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 2.0, 3.0, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 2.0, 3.5, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 2.0, 4.0, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 2.0, 4.5, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 2.0, 2.8, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 3.0, 3.0, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 3.0, 3.5, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 3.0, 4.0, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 3.0, 4.5, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 3.0, 5.0, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 4.0, 3.0, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 4.0, 3.3, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 4.0, 4.0, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 4.0, 4.5, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 4.0, 5.0, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 5.0, 4.0, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 5.0, 4.5, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 5.0, 3.8, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 5.0, 5.0, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 6.0, 4.7, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 6.0, 5.0, 0, 1.0, 0},
    {1, 7.0, 6.0, 0, 1.0, 0},
    //27
    ///gas
    {1, 3.0, 2.8, 0, 0, 1.0},
    {1, 4.0, 3.0, 0, 0, 1.0},
    {1, 5.0, 2.8, 0, 0, 1.0},
    {1, 5.0, 3.5, 0, 0, 1.0},
    {1, 6.0, 3.0, 0, 0, 1.0},
    {1, 6.0, 3.5, 0, 0, 1.0},
    {1, 6.0, 4.0, 0, 0, 1.0},
    {1, 6.0, 4.5, 0, 0, 1.0},
    {1, 7.0, 2.8, 0, 0, 1.0},
    {1, 7.0, 3.5, 0, 0, 1.0},
    {1, 7.0, 4.0, 0, 0, 1.0},
    {1, 7.0, 4.5, 0, 0, 1.0},
    {1, 7.0, 5.0, 0, 0, 1.0},
    {1, 7.0, 5.8, 0, 0, 1.0},
    //14
    };
};
int chooseParent(NeuralNet Population[POP]);

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    NeuralNet Population[POP];
    int Parents[POP/4];
    int nextgen =1; ///using nextgen to test if the loop is working

    for(int i =  0 ; i < POP ; i ++)
    {
        Population[i].calculateError();
    }
int A = 0;
int B = 1;
do{
    NeuralNet *Children = new NeuralNet[POP];
    for(int i =0 ; i < POP ;  i++)
    {
        A = rand()%20;
        B = rand()%20;
        crossOver(Population[A], Population[B], Children[i]);
        transferGenes(Children[i], Population[i]);
        Population[i].calculateError();
    }
    delete[] Children;
    Children = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < POP ;  i++)
    {
        cout << Population[i].getError() << endl;
    }cout << endl;
}while(Population[0].getError() > 60);
    return 0;
}

void fittestSpecies(NeuralNet n)
{
    cout << n.totalerror<< endl;
}


void transferGenes(NeuralNet a, NeuralNet &b) //transfer weights from a to b
{
    for(int i = 0; i < hidden-1 ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < inputs ;  j++)
            {
            b.weights1[i][j] = a.weights1[i][j];
            }
        }


    for(int i = 0; i < outputs ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < hidden ;  j++)
            {
                b.weights2[i][j] = a.weights2[i][j];
                }
            }
}


void crossOver(NeuralNet a, NeuralNet b, NeuralNet &c) ///crossover
{
    int random;
    for(int i = 0; i < hidden-1 ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < inputs ;  j++)
            {
                random = rand()%2;
                if(random ==  1)
                {
                    c.weights1[i][j] = a.weights1[i][j];
                }else{
                c.weights1[i][j] = b.weights1[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

    for(int i = 0; i < outputs ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < hidden ;  j++)
            {
                random = rand()%2;
                if(random ==  1)
                {
                    c.weights2[i][j] = a.weights2[i][j];
                }else{
                c.weights2[i][j] = b.weights2[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
}
int chooseParent(NeuralNet population[POP]) ///using probability to select parents
{
    int greatestError = population[0].getError();
    for(int i =1 ; i < POP ;  i++)
    {
        if(population[i].getError() > greatestError)
            greatestError = population[i].getError();
    }
    int totalFitness = 0;

    for(int i =0 ; i < POP; i++)
    {
      population[i].setScore(greatestError +1 - population[i].getError());
      totalFitness = totalFitness + population[i].getScore();
    }

    int random = rand()%totalFitness +1;
    int parentSelector = 0;
    int parentIndex;
    for(int i=0; parentSelector<random;i++)
    {
        parentSelector = parentSelector + population[i].getScore();
        parentIndex = i;
    }

    return parentIndex;
}

float randFloat()
{
    float f = static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX));
    int Pos_or_Neg = rand()%2;
    if(Pos_or_Neg)
    {
        return f;
    }else{
    return -f;
    }
}

float Sigmoid(float A)
{
    return 1/(1+exp(-A));
}
```

Comment: *"Stopped working"* - it was no longer responsive or did it terminate with an error?

Comment: Very nice, but what is your problem, and what is it related with c++?

Comment: Off topic. This has the smell of a bad idea in the offing: `srand(time(0));`. the intent of  `srand(time(NULL));` is clear to both readers and the compiler.

Comment: It's not obvious that `chooseParent` will always return a value smaller than `POP`.